# Скрыть колонку на планшетах

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Задача такова. 
  Есть класс `visible-tablet` (Планшеты от `979px` до `768px`) . 
Как сделать чтобы если скрывается данная колонка первая не растягивалась на всю ширину или это нормальная функциональность `bootstrap` ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
          <!--Sidebar content-->
        </div>
        <div class="span10 visible-tablet">
          <!--Body content-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ну да, это нормальный функционал.
Если надо чтобы содержимое скрылось, а место осталось - попробуйте поиграть с прозрачностью. Если дать колонке `opacity: 0` - то она не будет видна, но место свое будет занимать :)

Comment: @cyadvert, если написать то, что Вы посоветовали, то колонка будет активна, правильней будет свойство `visibility: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

В [bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), пора бы уже на него переходить, класс `.row` всегда состоит из 12 колонок, причём, если использовать `.col-xs-*`, то колонка будет занимать всегда столько, сколько ей указано. Это делается вот так:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <!--Sidebar content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 visible-sm-block">
            <!--Body content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```